# How to close a website opened using ShellExecute VB6

Tags: vb6

I use this code to open the website,

```
  Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

  ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "open", webURL, vbNullString, webBrowser, vbNormal
```

Now I want to close the site automatically after time limit.

Or Addonn in web Browser that will automatically close the current tab after some time (ex. 30 seconds)

any idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Change `ShellExecute` with `ShellExecuteEx` ([here is a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292108/2861476)) which returns you a handle to the started process in `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.hProcess`. Then, when timeout is reached, use `TerminateProcess` api call  ([another sample](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_terminate_process.html))